# Is this a good network configuration?

Tags: cisco, router, nat, traceroute, access-control

I am trying to configure ip sla for non directed link . I have configured static route to reach to non directed link

```
1 configured track
2 configured ip sla
3 configured access-list
4 configured NAT
5 configured Event Manager (eem)
```

[image]

to make reachability

```
  ip route 1.1.1.0 255.255.255.252 Serial4/1 //to reachable the ip sla ping to 1.1.1.0
```

ip sla configuration

```
  track 88 ip sla 44 reachability
  ip sla 44
  icmp-echo 1.1.1.1
  frequency 5
  ip sla schedule 44 life forever start-time now
```

track configuration

```
  track 88 ip sla 44 reachability
  ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.2 track 88
  ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 20.0.0.2 10
```

access-list configuration

```
  access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.8.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

event manager configuration

```
      event manager applet abc
      event track 88 state up
      action 1   cli command "enable"
      action 1.1 cli command " clear ip nat translation * "
      action 2   cli command "config t"
      action 3   cli command " no ip nat insid source list 100 int 4/0 over"
      action 4   cli command "ip nat inside source list 100 int s4/1 over"
      action 5   syslog msg "track up"

     event manager applet abcd
     event track 88 state down
     action 1   cli command "enable"
     action 1.1 cli command " clear ip nat translation * "
     action 2   cli command "config t"
     action 3   cli command "no ip nat inside source list 100 int s4/1 over"
     action 4   cli command "ip nat inside source list 100 int s4/0 over"
     action 5   syslog msg "track down"
```

please suggest me about this configuration it work perfect but I little bit confused about it that will it be go longer.or you can suggest me the better way thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You don't need the eem scripts.  You can configure both translations and the packets will be translated correctly depending on which interface is used.
2. Depending on the failure scenario, 1.1.1.1 could be reachable via R3-R4.  So your SLA will keep flipping up and down.
3. You could also run a routing protocol on the routers which would eliminate the need for IP SLA.

Comment: According to your option 3.If i configure routing protocol then the problem will be about NAT .dyanamic protocol passing via NAT i think not good idea.

Comment: And if R1 both directly connected interfaces ate UP then route-map doesn't make sense to translate.

Comment: According to your option 2 if i set icmp-echo 1.1.1.1 source-ip address 10.0.0.1 .will it be flipping again???

Comment: NAT does not apply to packets generated by the router.  You don't need a route-map.

Comment: You mean to use .access-list 1 permit any.ip nat inside source list 1 int s4/0 overload.ip nat inside source list 1 int s4/1 overload.no need rout map or anything else.i used eigrp to eliminate ip sla failure but eigrp becom up and down.

Comment: Yes.  You need to figure out why EIGRP isn't stable. Since you haven't posted your full configs, I can't give you anything more useful. Look at your logs for more info

Comment: But sir as i mentioned you already that i hve configured ip sla to 1.1.1.1 which is indirect link to R1 according to 1.1.1.1 failure the link between R1 to R2 and R1 to R3 not become to down and in this case two NAT will load balance.R2 and R3 consider as isp1 and isp2

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking from us. You have changed the scenario, so eigrp is not an option anymore.  If it works and you're happy with it, OK.